How can I remove "Get Started" from the Recommended section in Windows 11 Start?
After hours of research, it seems that in windows Pro/Enterprise there is not way to remove the Recommended section in the Windows 11 Start Menu.
With that in mind, I have computers and users managed by an AD and Group Policy is Enabled. We also have VMWare DEM installed for our virtual floating assignment (non persistent) machines.
Using Scripts, GPO, DEM, anything, is there a way that I can remove the "Get Started" program from the Recommended section of the Windows 11 Start menu?
I have compared Registry exports on the HKCU before and after unpinning the app and found nothing. Most blog posts that I found also state that the Get Started application is embedded into the user experience appx and can't be removed. If you try, you'll break stuff. I have tried Windows Configuration designer and found no policies i can exploit through CSP. I'm at my whits end.
I'm hoping I can use a script or something to unpin it at login, or add other items to the list to push it out of view, or something.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Is there a particular reason you want to get rid of this? The Recommended section will normally populate over time with the apps people use, and so will push the any default apps out naturally. I know it can be an annoyance, but besides annoyance is there another reason you want to get rid of it?

For physical machines or Virtual Dedicated Assignment (Persistent) machines, this doesn't matter particularly to me. It's our Virtual Machines that are non-persistent. These machines will reset after the user logs out and when they log in it will be a brand new computer. So this app will never go away for those users and I don't want the users to run this app and be recommended applications to install or settings to change. The users don't have permission to install, but this will add extra overhead to our department and broken hearts to users.

As you're an enterprise customer, I'd suggest you talk with your Microsoft support reps, especially as you note you've already tried the known solutions. Microsoft has often added small features like being able to remove things like this when asked, in subsequent patches.

Can you provide a screenshot of what your talking about exactly?

@music2myear I can say I haven't tried that yet. I'll give them a ring.

@John that's probably what it's going to boil down to.

@Ramhound Here is the image you requested. I highlighted the app with a red square.
